# Prove: Lie algebra generated by two $n\times n$ shift matrices is $\mathfrak{so}(n,\mathbb{C})$ ($n$ odd) or $\mathfrak{sp}(n,\mathbb{C})$ ($n$ even)

Tags: lie-algebras

I wish to have a proof for the following result:

Let $U_n$ be an $n\times n$ upper [shift matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_matrix), and $L_n = U_n^T$ be a lower shift matrix. For example,
$$
U_5 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix},
\quad 
L_5 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then the Lie algebra generated by $U_n$ and $L_n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}(n, \mathbb{C})$ when $n$ is odd, and is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sp}(n, \mathbb{C})$ when $n$ is even.

I tested this numerically with `GAP` over the field $\mathbb{Q}$: the Lie algebra generated by $U_{2n+1}$ and $L_{2n+1}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is of type $B_n$, while the Lie algebra generated by $U_{2n}$ and $L_{2n}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is of type $C_n$.

Comment: For which bilinear forms? For the standard quadratic form $\mathfrak{so}(n,\mathbb{C})$ is the space of skew-symmetric matrices, which does not contain $L_n$ or $U_n$.

Comment: @abx That should be part of the question. It should be some weird bilinear form which I could not determine.

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe you could say that $L_n$ and $U_n$ generate a Lie algebra *isomorphic* to $\mathfrak{so}(n,\mathbb{C})$ or $\mathfrak{sp}(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: @abx Thanks for the suggestion! I've made the change in the text.

Comment: You checked numerically with which values of $n$?

Comment: Here's a roadmap to a solution. (a) compute the space $B_n$ of invariant quadratic (for  $n$ odd) or alternating forms by $U_n$ and $L_n$. Then $B_n$ should be 1-dimensional and generated by a non-degenerate form (otherwise the conclusion fails), say $q$. So, the Lie subalgebra $g_n$ generated by $\{U_n,L_n\}$ preserves $q$, i.e., is contained in so(q), resp sp(q). (b) Show the latter inclusion is an equality, e.g., computing enough iterated brackets to obtain a good lower bound on the dimension of $g_n$?

Comment: @YCor I checked from 3 to 9.

Comment: Other remark: The standard representation is clearly (absolutely) irreducible, so the generated Lie algebra $g_n$ is semisimple (well, reductive, but with center contained in scalar matrices, and since $g_n$ consists of trace zero matrices, the center is trivial).

Comment: @YCor, I know reductivity as a condition on *all* representations. Under what circumstances can you check it by looking at a single representation?  (Is the relevant point that the representation is faithful?)

Comment: @LSpice Yes: any Lie subalgebra of $gl_n$ whose action is completely reducible (over a field of char 0) is reductive (=semisimple $\times$ abelian). A similar result holds for linear algebraic groups (with "reductive" in the usual sense of algebraic groups).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let ${\mathfrak g} $ be the Lie algebra generated by $U_n$ and $L_n$. It's easy to check that $U_n$ and $L_n$ preserve the bilinear form determined by the matrix with $1,-1,1,\ldots$ down the antidiagonal and zero elsewhere. So ${\mathfrak g}$ is contained in (a Lie algebra isomorphic to) $\mathfrak{so} _n$ for odd $n$, $\mathfrak{sp} _n$ for even $n$. Let's assume $n$ is odd; the argument is the same for even $n$. Clearly ${\mathfrak g}=\mathfrak{so} _3$ if $n=3$. In the general case, $[U_n, L_n]=H_n$ is a diagonal matrix with just two non-zero entries $\pm 1$ and $U_n-[H_n, U_n]$, resp. $L_n+[H_n, L_n]$ equals $U_{n-2}$, resp. $L_{n-2}$ in the "middle" matrix subalgebra. By induction, ${\mathfrak g}$ contains $\mathfrak{so} _{n-2}$. Now it's easy to see that $[H_n, U_n]$, resp. $[H_n, L_n]$ is a multiple of the "missing" positive, resp. negative root element, so in fact ${\mathfrak g}$ equals $\mathfrak{so} _n$.

Comment: This is very elegant. Thank you so much!